# Filtering DataFrame with a mean treshhold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, and I want to keep only columns, when their mean is over a certain treshhold.

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((20,20)))
mean_keep= (df.mean() > 0.5)
mean_keep= mean_keep[mean_keep == True]
df_new = df[mean_keep.index]
```

and it is working. However I wonder if there is a function  like "TAKE_ONLY_COLUMNS" that can reduce this to one line like

```
df_new = df[TAKE_ONLY_COLUMNS(df.mean() > 0.5)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) here:

```
df_new=df.loc[:,df.mean() > 0.5]
print(df_new)
```

This will automatically keep the columns where the condition is True.